# Color palette in animated GIF: Photoshop vs. FFMPEG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I have created both animated gif files with Photoshop CS5.1 (combining single frames; gif 128 with dithering) and FFMPEG via command line (converting a .mov file to a .gif file; -pix_fmt rgb24).

Photoshop's output resembles the original images much more than FFMPEG does in terms of colors. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Just a guess... FFMPEG probably doesn't use color management. You may find opening the FFMPEG Gif in Photoshop and using Edit > Assign Profile yields proper colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

More than ffmpeg a quite versatile tool to convert video clips to an animated GIF is the **[convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)** module from the Image Magick suite. After having installed the suite a most basic conversion can be done with:

```
convert -delay 1 input.mov output.gif
```

For more details especially on different methods for GIF conversion and color palette processing this great tutorial is recommended:

- [Image Magick: Video Handling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/video/)

Answer (score 2):

GIF is a lossy format. Every GIF export tool can use different compression methods--including how it may re-map colors.

Comment: So does anybody knows freeware that does a good job in converting a movie file to .gif while maintaining the quality as much as possible. I do not care so much about file size.

Comment: @Vincent I'd ask that as a new question...perhaps on SuperUser